# build python for android 64bit

Tags: android, python, c++, android-ndk, native

My team is working on an Android app which has a major part written in Python and interpreted using [python for android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android).

We've currently building the Python compiler armv7 on a build machine running Ubuntu 12.04 32bit and NDK10e (or NDK8 until recently).

We've been trying to compile it for armv8a (64 bit, mainly because Google just announced they will no longer allow new apps that don't pack 64 bit native libraries starting Aug 2019) without success for some time now. 
We're using an Ubuntu 16.04 64bit build machine and NDK10e standalone toolchain built for arm64 and gcc compiler (also tried with NDK16 and clang) and constantly get the following error:

```
    python$EXE ../../Tools/scripts/h2py.py -i '(u_long)' /usr/include/netinet/in.h
/home/liveu/core/LuSmartAndroidCore/out/build/Python/arm/Python-2.7.2/python: 11: /home/liveu/core/LuSmartAndroidCore/out/build/Python/arm/Python-2.7.2/python: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
Makefile:969: recipe for target 'Lib/plat-linux4' failed
make: *** [Lib/plat-linux4] Error 2
```

I tried to find solutions on other Python implementations for mobile, but it seems that nobody tried/succeeded until now to build the interpreter for 64 bit.

If someone has ideas on how to proceed further or what approach to pursue it will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: did you found out the solution bcs i have same probleme.

Comment: did you found out the solution bcs i have same probleme.